# Alignment of figures

Tags: floats, geometry

I am struggeling with the following problem:

I want to add some pictures to a report in a 2 column geometry. I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,german,14pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

    \begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
   \foreach \s in {1,...,\MaxNumOfSections}{
       %\IfFileExists
        \IfFileExists{D:/folder1/folder2/pictures\s.jpg}
{\includegraphics[width=.39\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{D:/folder1/folder2/pictures\s}{}
  \vspace{6mm}
}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Everything works very nice except that starting with the second row of the figures all figures are shifted to the right and they are not arranged on top of each other. How can I solve this (cosnetical) problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your codes result. Thank you

Comment: Try `\ifodd\s\relax\hfil\else\par\fi`  just before the end of the `\foreach`.

Comment: You may have a spurious space in your loop. Add a line-ending `%`; see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: @Werner: you are my hero! That did the trick, thank you!!!